# Is it possible to add a single view on layout that would be visible while recoding the screen but not visible on result video?

Tags: android, xml, video-recording

I want to make a screen recorder with custom views, that can change while recording but not to show them on video result of the record

Comment: Have you tried to do any of what you are describing?

Comment: I took camera preview bitmap, layout bitmap and emitted these to sharedFlow. SharedFlow collects those data, overlay and  converts to Frame and records to FFmpegFrameRecorder.
the problem is - if I do it synchronously, every frame
takes too long to process. The phone cannot make 30 frames per second. If I do this in parallel, the sharedFlow overflows and the app crashes @TheLibrarian